# Assign new value to a cell in pd.DataFrame which is a pd.Series when series index isn't unique

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my data if anyone wants to try to reproduce the problem:
https://github.com/LunaPrau/personal/blob/main/O_paired.csv

I have a pd.DataFrame (called O) of 1402 rows × 1402 columns with columns and index both as ['XXX-icsd', 'YYY-icsd', ...] and cell values as some np.float64, some np.nan and problematically, some as pandas.core.series.Series.

|  | 202324-icsd | 644068-icsd | 27121-icsd | 93847-icsd | 154319-icsd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202324-icsd | 0.000000 | 0.029729 | NaN | 0.098480 | 0.097867 |
| 644068-icsd | NaN | 0.000000 | NaN | 0.091311 | 0.091049 |
| 27121-icsd | 0.144897 | 0.137473 | 0.0 | 0.081610 | 0.080442 |
| 93847-icsd | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0.000000 | 0.005083 |
| 154319-icsd | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 0.000000 |

The problem is that some cells (e.g. `O.loc["192693-icsd", "192401-icsd"]`) contain a pandas.core.series.Series of form:

```
192693-icsd    0.129562
192693-icsd    0.129562
Name: 192401-icsd, dtype: float64
```

I'm struggling to make this cell contain only a np.float64.
I tried:

```
O.loc["192693-icsd", "192401-icsd"] = O.loc["192693-icsd", "192401-icsd"][0]
```

and other various known forms of assignnign a new value to a cell in pd.DataFrame, but they only assign a new element to the same series in this cell, e.g. if I do

```
O.loc["192693-icsd", "192401-icsd"] = 5
```

then when calling `O.loc["192693-icsd", "192401-icsd"]` I get:

```
192693-icsd    5.0
192693-icsd    5.0
Name: 192401-icsd, dtype: float64
```

How to modify `O.loc["192693-icsd", "192401-icsd"]` so that it is of type np.float64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that `df.loc["192693-icsd", "192401-icsd"]` contain a Series, your index just isn't unique. This is especially obvious looking at these outputs:

```
>>> df.loc["192693-icsd"]
             202324-icsd  644068-icsd  27121-icsd  93847-icsd  154319-icsd  28918-icsd  28917-icsd  ...  108768-icsd  194195-icsd  174188-icsd  159632-icsd  89111-icsd  23308-icsd  253341-icsd
192693-icsd          NaN          NaN         NaN         NaN     0.146843         NaN         NaN  ...          NaN     0.271191          NaN          NaN         NaN         NaN     0.253996
192693-icsd          NaN          NaN         NaN         NaN     0.146843         NaN         NaN  ...          NaN     0.271191          NaN          NaN         NaN         NaN     0.253996

[2 rows x 1402 columns]

# And the fact that this returns the same:
>>> df.at["192693-icsd", "192401-icsd"]
192693-icsd    0.129562
192693-icsd    0.129562
Name: 192401-icsd, dtype: float64
```

You can fix this with a groupby, but you have to decide what to do with the non-unique groups. It looks like they're the same, so we'll combine them with max:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).max()
```

Now it'll work as expected:

```
>>> df.loc["192693-icsd", "192401-icsd"])
0.129562120551387
```

---

Your non-unique values are:

```
>>> df.index[df.index.duplicated()]
Index(['193303-icsd', '192693-icsd', '416602-icsd'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thank you - that was it! I updated the question to reflect what the problem actually is

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try `DataFrame.applymap` to check each cell type and get the first row if it is Series

```py
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.iloc[0] if type(x) == pd.Series else x)
```

Comment: thanks for this solution, however it doesn't actually change the values as I want to - it works in the same way as my example with assigning "5" and still leaves a series in place with the values changed

Comment: @mchrnwsk What's your pandas version?

Comment: pandas version 1.4.3

Comment: @mchrnwsk It's weird since I couldn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I added a [link](https://github.com/LunaPrau/personal/blob/main/O_paired.csv) to a github with my data if you're still interested in giving it a try - thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected for `O.loc["192693-icsd", "192401-icsd"] = O.loc["192693-icsd", "192401-icsd"][0]`

Check this colab link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1XFXuj4OBu8GXQx6DTqv04XellmFcFWbC?usp=sharing

Comment: thank you, I see this works for you - and it works for me too using your exact commands, but somehow my df doesn't cooperate in the same way... I will go a roundabout way of making a new df and adding to its cells O.loc["192693-icsd", "192401-icsd"][0] values if that cell is a Series